# Recursive record update by flow

Tags: workflow, process-builder, visual-workflow, recursion

I have a simple process builder that triggers a flow to update a record and whenever the flow does, all the workflows and process builders related to the object are triggered the second time. 
Is there any way to stop triggering the process builders and workflows when a flow updates the record.

I know we have the advanced option in the process criteria but I can't use it as 'ISCHANGED' is one of my criteria.

[image]

Comment: Can you please include screenshot of your process builder, with sensitive information cleared.

Answer (score 0):

The re-evaluation of processes and workflow rules is the expected behavior when updating a record from an autolaunched flow.

See step 14 from the the docs for [order of execution](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm)

> When a process or flow executes a DML operation, the
> affected record goes through the save procedure.

As a workaround, you can have the flow mark a checkbox or some other field on the record to indicate the flow has been executed. The conditions of the other processes and workflows could then use this field to determine if the flow has already completed.